# Unexpected space (not sure what the type of character this space is) while parsing csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, python-requests, whitespace

I am iterating through a list of urls from a csv file trying to locate their sitemaps, however, I am getting a weird leading space issue that's causing an error to occur when requests processes each url.  I'm trying to figure out what's causing this space to be generated and what type of space it is.  I believe something funky is happening with strip() because I can get this to run fine when copying and pasting a url into requests.  I am just not sure what type of space this is and what's causing it to occur.

Wondering if anyone else is having or had this issue?
So far I have tried to solve using the following methods:

```
replace()
"".join(split())
regex
```

Here is my code:

```
with open('links.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        strdomain = line.strip()
        if strdomain:
            domain = strdomain
            fix_domain = domain.replace('https://', '').replace('www', '').replace('/', '').replace('.', '').replace(' ', '')
            ofile = fix_domain + '.txt'  # args.ofile
            domain_rem = domain
            map = find_sitemap.get_sitemap(domain_rem+"sitemap.xml")
            url_info = find_sitemap.parse_sitemap(map)
            print("Found {0} urls".format(len(url_info)))
            new_urls = []
            for u in url_info:
                new_urls.append(u)
                print(u)
```

links.csv look like the following with just one column:

```
https://site1.com/
https://site2.com/
https://site3.com/
```

I printed `domain` and `strdomain` and even added the word "this" next to the variable `domain` so you can see the space being produced clearly:

[image]

Here is the error I receive in full when running (you will notice there is no leading space within the url after I've copied and pasted from the terminal into here however I provide an image of my terminal below so you can see it):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/natehurwitz/PROJECTS/axis/axis/apps/axisDataFinder/map_website.py", line 358, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/natehurwitz/PROJECTS/axis/axis/apps/axisDataFinder/map_website.py", line 318, in main
    map = find_sitemap.get_sitemap(domain_rem+"sitemap.xml")
  File "/Users/natehurwitz/PROJECTS/axis/axis/apps/axisDataFinder/find_sitemap.py", line 5, in get_sitemap
    get_url = requests.get(url)
  File "/Users/natehurwitz/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/axis-eSvach19-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/natehurwitz/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/axis-eSvach19-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/natehurwitz/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/axis-eSvach19-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 522, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/natehurwitz/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/axis-eSvach19-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 636, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "/Users/natehurwitz/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/axis-eSvach19-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 727, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'https://blkgrn.com/sitemap.xml'
```

[Here is where you can see the leading space that occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTuXD.png)

Here is the code for "find_sitemap.py":

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_sitemap(url):
    get_url = requests.get(url)

    if get_url.status_code == 200:
        return get_url.text
    else:
        print ('Unable to fetch sitemap: %s.' % url)


def process_sitemap(s):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "lxml")
    result = []

    for loc in soup.findAll('loc'):
        item = {}
        item['loc'] = loc.text
        item['tag'] = loc.parent.name
        if loc.parent.lastmod is not None:
            item['lastmod'] = loc.parent.lastmod.text
        if loc.parent.changeFreq is not None:
            item['changeFreq'] = loc.parent.changeFreq.text
        if loc.parent.priority is not None:
            item['priority'] = loc.parent.priority.text
        result.append(item)

    return result

def is_sub_sitemap(s):
    if s['loc'].endswith('.xml') and s['tag'] == 'sitemap':
        return True
    else:
        return False

def parse_sitemap(s):
    sitemap = process_sitemap(s)
    result = []

    while sitemap:
        candidate = sitemap.pop()

        if is_sub_sitemap(candidate):
            sub_sitemap = get_sitemap(candidate['loc'])
            for i in process_sitemap(sub_sitemap):
                sitemap.append(i)
        else:
            result.append(candidate)

    return result
```

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but what if a url actually contained www? For example ,`https://mysite-www.com`, then you're removing it (and all dots) and ending up `mysite-com.txt`

Comment: Please include `find_sitemap.py` in your question

Comment: Added the traceback error, sorry about that, included a pic too, leading space dissapears when I go to copy/paste it anywhere

Comment: There are a few functions you can use to see what's at the start of your string such as `ord(...)`, `repr(...)`, and `unicodedata.name(...)`.

Comment: Added find_sitemap.py

Comment: [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print `line`, `strdomain`, `domain`, `domain_rem` in the except suite using repr
 or ord - like : `print([(c,ord(c)) for c in s])`, or `print(repr(s))`. It is probably in your file.

Comment: I think I found the culprit, here's what that space is - '\ufeff''

Comment: This is the whole print - [('\ufeff', 65279), ('h', 104), ('t', 116), ('t', 116), ('p', 112), ('s', 115), (':', 58), ('/', 47), ('/', 47), ('b', 98), ('l', 108), ('k', 107), ('g', 103), ('r', 114), ('n', 110), ('.', 46), ('c', 99), ('o', 111), ('m', 109), ('/', 47)]

Comment: Is there a way I can encode this variable to utf-8 so it skips this item?

Comment: Solved, here is what did it:

Comment: open('links.csv', encoding="utf-8-sig") - just add utf-8-sig , this removes the BOM causing this issue thank you everyone!!